# Facing Issue in send object data to mongodb database in my nodejs application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I m using postman for post the data, sample is given below,after this it is giving error which i don't understand where i doing mistake,kindly some one help on this.

Error: order validation failed: Orditems.0.id: Path id is required., Orditems.0.dishName: Path
dishName is required., Orditems.0.image: Path image is required., Orditems.0.price: Path
price is required., Orditems.0.qty: Path qty is required., Orditems.0.total: Path total is
required.

```
{
        "name":"manoj sahni",
        "mobile":12345678,
        "ultermobile":21545544,
        "address":"bhopal fsfadff dfgdsg",
        "grandTotal":414,
        "orderid":"64gd4gd",
        "paymentid":"fghfh4f4",
        "items":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "dishName":"samaychiken",
                "image":"muttonsaamey.jpg",
                "price":200,
                "qty":2,
                "total":230
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "dishName":"samaychiken",
                "image":"muttonsaamey.jpg",
                "price":210,
                "qty":"1",
                "total":210
            }
        ]
    }
```

Model

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const ordSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    Orditems:[{
        id:{type:Number,required:true},
        dishName:{type:String,required:true},
        image:{type:String,required:true},
        price:{type:Number,required:true},
        qty:{type:Number,required:true},
        total:{type:Number,required:true}    
    }],
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    mobile:{type:Number,required:true},
    ultermobile:Number,
    address:{type:String,required:true},
    grandTotal:{type:Number,required:true},
    orderid:{type:String},
    paymentid:{type:String},
    created_at:{type:Date,default:new Date()}
},{timestamps:true})

const ordr=new mongoose.model('order',ordSchema)
module.exports=ordr
```

Route

```
    router.post('/invOrders',async(req,res)=>{
        invData1=req.body
        invData2=req.body.items
        console.log("invorder data",invData1);
        console.log("invorder data2",invData2)
    
        try {
            const ordr=new ordersModel(
                {
                    Orditems:[{id:invData2.id,
                               dishName:invData2.dishName,
                               image:invData2.image,
                               price:invData2.price,
                               qty:invData2.qty,
                               total:invData2.total
                             }],
                    name:invData1.name,
                    mobile:invData1.mobile,
                    ultermobile:invData1.ultermobile,
                    address:invData1.address,
                    grandTotal:invData1.grandTotal,
                    orderid:invData1.orderid,
                    paymentid:invData1.paymentid,
                    
            }
            )
           const invSave= await ordr.save(err=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log("inv errr",err)
                }
           },
           succ=>{
                if(succ){
                    console.log("invoice save ",succ)
                }
           })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("catch error",error)
        }
        
    })
    module.exports=router
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.body.items` is an array, the problem is that you are trying to access it as an object.
Try to assign it directly to the `Orditems` property when creating the new instance:

```
router.post('/invOrders', async (req, res) => {
  invData1 = req.body;
  invData2 = req.body.items;

  try {
    const ordr = new ordersModel({
      Orditems: invData2,
      name: invData1.name,
      mobile: invData1.mobile,
      ultermobile: invData1.ultermobile,
      address: invData1.address,
      grandTotal: invData1.grandTotal,
      orderid: invData1.orderid,
      paymentid: invData1.paymentid,
    });

    const invSave = await ordr.save(
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('inv errr', err);
        }
      },
      (succ) => {
        if (succ) {
          console.log('invoice save ', succ);
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('catch error', error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```